# Session_start does not maintain variables on homepage only

Tags: php, session

I use PHP sessions with `session_start()` to maintain state of which user is logged into my site. This works fine by just calling `session_start()` and the top of all my files once the user is logged in.

However, I'd like to have it so when they click the site's icon in the menu bar, if they are logged in it won't send them to the homepage but rather to their logged in personal page. However, a simple `session_start()` to recognize the user is logged in and redirect them at the top of the homepage does not work.

None of the session variables are recognized from the home page. Yet the session is not actually killed - I can go back in the history and am still logged into the site. Would there be a reason the homepage should give different behavior than every other page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it shouldn't be different.
In order to see what variables are available in your $_SESSION, you can do this

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

If it's empty then there is a problem. You can try to see the session_id with the method

```
echo session_id();
```

It should be the same session_id in both your logged page and home page. If this is not the case, maybe you are messing up with cookies?

Comment: The session_id does vary between the two pages, while it stays the same within all "logged in pages" (everything except the home page). Yet session_start() is definitely being called at the top, and only once. Any ideas where the cookies could be getting messed up?

Comment: have a look on http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php why your session_id might be different? you can have a look at the COOKIE which seems to be PHPSESSID. Make sure also you don't have the use of session_regenerate_id(). So look how your cookie is going around here... that might be the key

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `session_start()` is only being called once.  If you call it twice, it could interfere with the session handling.  I would recommend that you call session_start() on every page the user can be logged in on (frankly I see no reason not to call it on every page period, but someone please correct me if this is bad) but only *once*.  At that point, you can check the `_SESSION` and see if the user's logged in key is set.  If so, redirect them.

Answer (score 0):

if u are calling `session_start()` on each page and you don't know that a session is already strated in your *include/require* pages then use **@** like this `@session_start()`

***note:*** although this is not good practice to use **@**

> to send a user to their personal page rather than home page

..u need to develop a logic and also personal page will be based on user id of logged user.On home page something like below

#### home.php(raw code)

```
<?php if(!empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
header("Location : personal_page.php?id=".$_SESSION['user_id']);
exit();
} else {
//your page code
}
?>
```

> for  login via history pages problem:

you create a *logout.php* to end user session, do not forget to start the session in this page!, using `session_start()` at the very begging of your script. Thus,

```
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

will be the right sequence to end a user's session.

[reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php)

Happy To Help :)